# ¿Es posible solicitar la activación del GPS con phonegap?

Tags: phonegap

Estoy utilizando el plugin de: cordova-plugin-geolocation. El problema es que si el dispositivo tiene desactivado el gps no muestra el mapa.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta e incluye el código que usas para mostrar el mapa y obtener los datos de geolocalización

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Podrías comprobar si el GPS está activado. Este plugin proporciona métodos para conocer el estado del hardware del dispositivo:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic

De acuerdo con la documentación:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#islocationenabled

podrías usar este método para mostrar el mapa en la función de callback `successCallback` y mostrar un mensaje de error indicando que es necesario activar el sensor GPS para poder visualizar el mapa en la función de callback `errorCallback`

Comment: Tengo instalado el plugin de geolocation pero cuando agrego este plugin no me compila  por dependencias.

Comment: ¿Lo añades con el comando npm?

Comment: no con el cordova, es el que estoy utilizando para mi proyecto